# Working with substitute after `$` sign in R

Tags: r, function, subset

I was wondering if there is a way that `G` in my code below could work after `$` just like `D$post == 1` works?

```
D <- data.frame(post = 1:10, out = 2:11)

G <- substitute(post == 1)

D$G    ## can we make `G` to work like `D$post`?

D$post == 1  ## Works
```

Comment: @joran, I know that but that doesn't fit my purpose.

Comment: it might help to give a little bit more context about your problem.  The specific short-cut you want (macro-substitution) is going to be very hard to get working, I think, but if you give a more general goal someone might be able to provide a reasonable solution ...

Comment: e.g.  with tidyverse, `library(dplyr); f <- function(d,x) {filter(d,{{x}})}` gets you a generic selection function, so `f(D,post==1)` or `D %>% f(post==1)` works (although here almost trivially)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
G <- substitute(post == 1)
E <- substitute(D$G, list(G = G))
#D$post == 1
```

That expression looks like what you want, right? Well, it isn't, as you can see when you try to evaluate it:

```
eval(E)
#Error in D$post == 1 : invalid subscript type 'language'
```

Let's inspect the expression in more detail:

```
as.list(E)
#[[1]]
#`$`
#
#[[2]]
#D
#
#[[3]]
#post == 1
```

OK, we have one function call (to `$`)  with two arguments (`D` and `post == 1`). The second argument is an expression whereas `$` expects a name.

Let's compare this with how it should look like:

```
as.list(quote(D$post == 1))
#[[1]]
#`==`
#
#[[2]]
#D$post
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1

as.list(quote(D$post == 1)[[2]])
#[[1]]
#`$`
#
#[[2]]
#D
#
#[[3]]
#post
```

So, `D$post == 1` is actually a call to two nested functions and get's parsed to this:

```
`==`(`$`(D, post), 1)
```

I hope this clarifies why "[w]orking with substitute after $ sign" is not so simple.

Just to show that is still possible, if you understand how the expression is parsed:

```
E <- quote(D$x)
E[[3]] <- G[[2]]
G[[2]] <- E
eval(G)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

However, such code is really hard to maintain and debug. Don't do this.

As @joran shows, you can use functions like `with` that evaluate the expression `post == 1` within the data.frame, which is basically just a wrapper for  `eval(G, D, parent.frame())`. However, that's a dangerous and slippery path that can lead to dragons. Let me quote the relevant warning from `help("subset")` here:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset
>   can have unanticipated consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something more like this:

```
q <- quote(post == 1)
with(D,eval(q))
```