# A replacement for `subset()` for a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, subset

Function `foo1` can subset (using `subset()`) a list of data.frames by one or more requested variables (e.g., `by = ESL == 1` or `by == ESL == 1 & type == 4`).

However, I'm aware of the [**danger of using `subset()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863081/7223434) in R. Thus, I wonder in `foo1` below, what I can use instead of `subset()` to get the same output?

```
foo1 <- function(data, by){

  s <- substitute(by)
  L <- split(data, data$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

  lapply(L, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s))) ## What to use instead of `subset`
                                                       ## to get the same output?
}

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", header=TRUE) # DATA
foo1(D, ESL == 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute on the language. Building on my answer to ["Working with substitute after `$` sign in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57420979/1412059):

```
foo1 <- function(data, by){

  s <- substitute(by)
  L <- split(data, data$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

  E <- quote(x$a)
  E[[3]] <- s[[2]]
  s[[2]] <- E

  eval(bquote(lapply(L, function(x) x[.(s),])))
}

foo1(D, ESL == 1)
```

This gets more complex for arbitrary subset expressions. You'd need a recursive function that crawls the parse tree and inserts the calls to `$` at the right places.

Personally, I'd just use package data.table where this is easier because you don't need `$`, i.e., you can just do `eval(bquote(lapply(L, function(x) setDT(x)[.(s),])))` without changing `s`. OTOH, I wouldn't do this at all. There is really no reason to split before subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess (based on general knowledge and a quick skim of the answers to the ["dangers of subset()" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863081/7223434)) that the dangers of `subset` are **intrinsic dangers of non-standard evaluation** (NSE); if you want to be able to pass a generic expression and have it evaluated within the context of a data frame, I think you're more or less stuck with `subset()` or something like it.

If you were willing to use a more constrained set of expressions such as `var`, `vals` (looking for cases where the variable indexed by string `var` took on values in the vector `vals`) you could use

```
d[d[[var]] %in% vals, ]
```

Here `var` is a **string**, not a naked R symbol (`"cyl"` rather than `cyl`); it's unambiguous that you want to extract it from the data frame.

You could extend this to a vector of variables and a list of vectors of values:

```
for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
   d <- d[d[[vars[i]]] %in% vals[[i]], ]
}
```

but if you want the full flexibility of expressions (e.g. to be able to use either `ESL == 1 & type == 4` or `ESL == 1 | type == 4`, or inequalities based on numeric variables) I think you're stuck with an NSE-based approach.

It's conceivable that the new-ish "tidy eval" machinery (in the `rlang` package, documented in some detail [here](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/)) would give you a slightly more principled approach, but I don't think the dangers will completely go away.